# How to call mapconcat with variable?

Tags: list, emacs

In My `.emacs` file, I have

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
      #'(lambda ()
          (setenv "PATH"
                  (mapconcat 'identity '("/usr/local/bin" (getenv "PATH")) ":"))))
```

I want to prepend "/usr/local/bin" to the `PATH` variable. But when I execute `eshell`, I got **setenv: Wrong type argument: characterp, getenv**.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the `getenv` part of the list, so you can't quote it as a whole:

```
(mapconcat 'identity `("/usr/local/bin" ,(getenv "PATH")) ":")
```

or

```
(mapconcat 'identity (list "/usr/local/bin" (getenv "PATH")) ":")
```